# how can I access this inside a function without using that or self in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to write some OOP in javascript, and I stumbled upon a problem that I am sure Im going to have later on in my code and wish to deal with it now.

for example take this code:

```
var FeedClass = function(){

    this.init = function(){
        this.loadItems();
    },
    this.loadItems = function(){
        var that = this; // heres my problem
        function inner(){
            that.startLoading();
        }
        inner();
    },
    this.startLoading = function(){
        alert("started Loading");
    }

    this.init();
};

var feed = new FeedClass();
```

the problem is Im going to use a lot of inner functions that will call `"this"`, my code will be messy if I kept writing `var that = this` inside every scope. Is there another pattern I can use or a way to get around it?

Comment: You should perhaps check the [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method in javascript. It might answer your question

Comment: @Jhecht thanks, could you possibly give me an example of using `bind()' with the code above, so i can see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context for the function:

```
this.loadItems = function(){
    function inner(){
        this.startLoading();
    }
    inner.call(this);
},
```

The [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) works similarly, the difference is how you specify parameters in the call.

You can also use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context of a function. That allows you to bind the context to the function and pass the function reference on to be called later:

```
this.loadItems = function(){
    function inner(){
        this.startLoading();
    }
    var i = inner.bind(this);
    i();
},
```

Note: The `bind` method is not supported in IE 8 or earlier.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i wanted to hear.

Comment: This also does the same (**effectively**) the same thing as `.bind` If you'd like I could make an answer to show you some of the differences.